# Best way to backup a WSS / SharePoint wiki?

Tags: wiki, wss-3.0, backup, 2007

We're using WSS to track a project I'm working on, and I'm storing a lot of research within the wiki that I'd like to keep backups of.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to go about this?  Is there some way to export/import wiki content?  Or would it be better to backup the raw database -- if so, which tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I think would be to export your Wiki site from the server using stsadm.

I strongly advise against looking into the raw database, particularly for backup purposes as your backup will almost never be recoverable.

Chris O'Brien has a good blog post on this with examples:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/10/stsadm-export-content-deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

hm....Export woudl work as James advice.
But if you backup your database or you do a file backup using stsadm it should be fine.
Is the WIKI site inside another root site?
Just back up the root site were the WIKI is and it should be fine.
I did migrate a couple and at last i got it up and running.
See this too :http://wikimigrator.codeplex.com/ 
Hope that helps